# Passing value between form and class winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, null, var

I'm traying to pass a value from a form to a class to determinate the level in which the game will be, but it keeps passing with 0 value.

I need to pass "nivelElegido" with the values 1 or 2

```
 int nivelElegido;

 private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     nivelElegido = 1;

     Form1 frm = new Form1();
     frm.Show();
     this.Hide();          
 }

 private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     nivelElegido = 2;
     Form1 frm = new Form1();
     frm.Show();
 }

 public int niveEle
 {
     get { return nivelElegido; }
 }
```

I change the value and in the other form try to use it.

```
 using (var nivelarmando = new NivelArmando())
 {
     niveleleg = nivelarmando.niveEle;
 }
 pala.nivo = niveleleg;
 pala.Traelo();
```

`pala.traelo` brings data from a class and `pala.nivo` is the level.

```
public void Traelo()
{
    if (nivo==1)
    {
    }
    else if (nivo==2)
    {
    }
```

But `nivo` comes with a 0 instead of 1 or 2. How can I do?

Comment: There are a few ways this could be done, probably the easiest would be to make nivelElegido static.

Comment: what is `NivelArmando`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the top code is from the NivelArmando class.  If so, this code

```
 using (var nivelarmando = new NivelArmando())
 {
     niveleleg = nivelarmando.niveEle;
 }
```

is creating a new instance of NivelArmando, and in that case, *nivelElegido* will be initialized to 0.  *niveleleg* will then be set to zero and not see the value that you modified elsewhere.

You should create a property on Form1 or pass the value of *nivelElegido* to the constructor of Form1 and then use that value in *Traelo()* function.

Answer (score 0):

Get and set the variable with variables.nivelElegido = 1
Read with variables.nivelElegido

```
Public Class variables

    Public Shared Property nivelElegido() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_nivelElegido
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_nivelElegido = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Shared m_nivelElegido As Integer

End Class
```